# replace xml particular node element value with other value in mule

Tags: mule

```
<healthcare>
    <plans>
        <plan1>
            <planid>100</planid>
            <planname>medical</planname>
            <desc>medical</desc>
            <offerprice>500</offerprice>
            <area>texas</area>
        </plan1>
        <plan2>
            <planid>101</planid>
            <planname>dental</planname>
            <desc>dental</desc>
            <offerprice>1000</offerprice>
            <area>texas</area>
        </plan2>
    </plans>
</healthcare>



<splitter evaluator="xpath" expression="/healthcare/plans" doc:name="Splitter"/> 
<transformer ref="domToXml" doc:name="Transformer Reference"/> 
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" message=" plans   detils...#[message.payload]" />
```

i want replace offerprice value with other values during runtime.anyhelp appreciated.I tried various various ways . anyone shed light means it saves me lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use XSLT and use identity templates to replace the one element.Or if your really want to do it with MEL, convert to DOM and use Dom4j APIs to set the value and then convert back to XML if needed:

```
    <expression-component><![CDATA[
          node = message.payload.getRootElement().selectSingleNode('//plans/plan1/planid');
          node.text = 'newvalue';
        ]]></expression-component>

    <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer />

    <logger level="ERROR" message=" #[payload]" />
```

**EDIT**

Here is an example if you want to update multiple nodes. If the transformation gets any more complex, I would really suggest taking a look at XSLT.

```
<mulexml:xml-to-dom-transformer             returnClass="org.dom4j.Document" />

        <expression-component><![CDATA[
                plans =  message.payload.getRootElement().selectNodes('//plans/*');
                foreach (plan : plans){
                    plan.selectSingleNode('offerprice').text = '3000';
                }       ]]></expression-component>

        <mulexml:dom-to-xml-transformer />

        <logger level="ERROR" message=" #[payload]" />
```

Comment: it shows indival node set like below<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plan2>
            <planid>500</planid>
            <planname>dental</planname>
            <desc>dental</desc>
            <offerprice>1000</offerprice>
            <area>texas</area>
        </plan2>   but i want all original xml element with replaced valued

Comment: don't split it then. And change the dom4j xpath expression to pick a particular node. I have updated my answer

Comment: Hi, suppose i change offerprice value like 3000 means .i expect output like below one  <healthcare>
    <plans>
        <plan1>
            <planid>600</planid>
            <planname>medical</planname>
            <desc>medical</desc>
            <offerprice>3000</offerprice>
            <area>texas</area>
        </plan1>
        <plan2>
            <planid>600</planid>
            <planname>dental</planname>
            <desc>dental</desc>
            <offerprice>3000</offerprice>
            <area>texas</area>
        </plan2>
    </plans>
</healthcare>

Comment: anyhow thanks for answer. But  my requirement is like replaced values with whole xml like above . not indiviual tags. please suggest

Comment: i'm new to mule ESB. please suggest for my requirement added in my above comments

Comment: please suggest. Ryan Carter

Comment: Hi the above same using xpath3 means , what is flow. Using xpath i have working flow .but xpath going to be depreceted in mule 4.0. please xpath3 for above same requirment

Comment: The above example does not use the deprecated xpath expression evaluator? It uses MVEL and the DOM4J APIs directly.