# how to replace value using xpath3 expression in mule esb

Tags: mule

```
 <babyproducts>
       <products>
           <product1>
               <productid>100</productid>
               <productname>towel</productname>
               <desc>towel</desc>
               <discount>100</discount>
               <validlity>10</validlity>
           </product1>
           <product2>
               <productid>101</productid>
               <productname>pillow</productname>
               <desc>pillow</desc>
               <discount>500</discount>
               <validlity>5</validlity>
           </product2>
       </product>
</babyproducts>
```

I want to split above xml using **xpath3 expression** and replace the validlity value . after that i want whole set of above xml replaced values. I tried using xpath it is working fine.  **my requirement insists on doing using xpath3 mule expression**

```
<splitter evaluator="xpath" expression="/babyproducts/products" doc:name="Splitter" />  
  <set-payload value="#[message.payload]" doc:name="Set Payload" />
  <enricher source="#[flowVars.newvalidlity]" target="#[xpath('/products/validlity').text ]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
     <logger level="INFO" message=" enricher done ~~~~~.." doc:name="Logger" />
  </enricher>
```

**above is my mule flow using xpath.  my team wants to do using xpath3 (latest)**.

my expected outpu is like below with new validlity value 50 (comes from flow variable)

```
<babyproducts>
       <products>
           <product1>
               <productid>100</productid>
               <productname>towel</productname>
               <desc>towel</desc>
               <discount>100</discount>
               <validlity>50</validlity>
           </product1>
           <product2>
               <productid>101</productid>
               <productname>pillow</productname>
               <desc>pillow</desc>
               <discount>500</discount>
               <validlity>50</validlity>
           </product2>
       </product>
</babyproducts>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [replace xml particular node element value with other value in mule](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30071432/replace-xml-particular-node-element-value-with-other-value-in-mule)

Comment: no this is different situtation arises from my technical management team my requirement insists on doing using xpath3 mule expression. No it is for other requirement  particularly using xpath3

Comment: Can you post your existing xpath configuration then?

Comment: I updated my mule flow and expected output in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all your XML sample is invalid. There are unclosed tags and your xpath doesn't match the structure of the sample either.

Second of all I can only show the equivalent xpath3 expression of your xpath expression as I have already answered how to update an XML node in other questions of yours.

```
<splitter evaluator="xpath" expression="/babyproducts/products" doc:name="Splitter" />
```

Becomes:

```
<splitter expression="#[xpath3('/babyproducts/products/*', payload, 'NODESET')]"
            doc:name="Splitter" />
```

And

```
#[xpath('/products/validlity').text]
```

Becomes:

```
 #[xpath3('/products/validlity')]
```

No need for .text as by default returns the Stirng value. More info here: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/mule-3-6-xml-xpath-xslt-xquery3/

Comment: Hi, I didn't get any expected above output  (added in my question)  using xpath3 . anyone share the xapth3 flow

Comment: Thank you for this.  Still pretty new to mule so this was incredibly helpful after finding online resources referencing xpath and wanting to make sure my code is more future proof for MULE4